# Solution of Integral equation via Fourier Transform

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-equations

> Solve for f(t) using Fourier transform:
> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s)f(t-s)\,ds
> - 2\sqrt{2}
>   \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s^2/\pi}f(t-s)\,ds
>  = -\sqrt{2}\pi e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2\pi}}
> $$

Now, I get the point that we have a convolution in place of both the integrals, giving me (using the fourier transform, denoted by $F$ here):

$$
F(f(t))^{2}-2\sqrt{2}F\left(e^{-t^2/\pi}\right)F(f(t))
 = -\sqrt{2}\pi F\left(e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2\pi}}\right)
$$

...but I can't wrap my mind around how to further simplify this, since

$$F(e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{\pi}})\neq F(e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{2\pi}}).$$

What are my next steps - what am I not seeing?

Comment: Can't you solve for $F(f(t))$ using quadratic formula?

Comment: Why don't you calculate the Fourier transform of a Gaussian first? You will notice a similarity (like one is the square of the other, multiplied with a constant)

Comment: @gt6989b I tried that just now, thing is I still have to do the fourier transforms of the Gaussians again - in my opinion, this task relies on the use of fourier transform theorems, like the convolution theorem, allowing us to skip solving the fourier transforms themselves...

Comment: When you use quadratic formula, in the discriminant you will get $F^2(e^{-t^2/\pi})$ and $F(e^{-t^2/(2\pi)})$. The only way to relate them is to know that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a new Gaussian, with width the inverse of the original.